# Matplotlib: how to set quiver length?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The quiver and quiverkey are a bit of a mystery to me and I have not found a good answer yet and hence this.

I want to compare the wind fields between two datasets. How do I set lets say 5 m/s wind quiver to be of a certain fixed length (e.g. 2 figure units) so that I can compare two plots? I am pretty sure this is trivial, but with so many arguments to the call, I can't really figure out what is really going on. Any help is  greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
q = plt.quiver(x, y, u, v, scale=150)
plt.quiverkey(q, 0.8, -0.1, 10, '10 m/s', labelpos='E')
```

this seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=2)

plt.show()
```